# Javascript get index of same class repeated multiple times in html page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the index of same class repeated multiple times in different structure. For example `single-row` is my class name and

```
<div class="somediv1">
    <div class="somediv2">
        <div class="somediv3">
            <div class="single-row">
                <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="somediv1">
    <div class="somediv2">
        <div class="somediv3">
            <div class="somediv4">
                <div class="single-row">
                    <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="somediv1">
    <div class="single-row">
        <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="single-row">
    <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
</div>
```

And below is the javascript code that I tried to get the index of my class `single-row` by on-click function:

```
.on('click', "#product-name", function (e) {
    var index = $(this).parents(".single-row").index();
    //var index = $(".single-row").index(this);
    alert(index);
})
```

But I'm not getting the proper index for each `div`.

Live example:

```js
$(document).on('click', "#product-name", function(e) {
  var index = $(this).parents(".single-row").index();
  //var index = $(".single-row").index(this);
  alert(index);
})
```

```html
<div class="somediv1">
   <div class="somediv2">
    <div class="somediv3">
      <div class="single-row">
        <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="somediv1">
   <div class="somediv2">
    <div class="somediv3">
       <div class="somediv4">
      <div class="single-row">
         <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="somediv1">
  <div class="single-row">
         <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="single-row">
         <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you add the expected result ? I am having a hard time trying to understand what you want / need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  `$(this).parent().index(".single-row");`

```js
$(document).on('click', "#product-name", function(e) {
  var index = $(this).parent().index(".single-row");
  //var index = $(".single-row").index(this);
  alert(index);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="somediv1">
   <div class="somediv2">
    <div class="somediv3">
      <div class="single-row">
        <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="somediv1">
   <div class="somediv2">
    <div class="somediv3">
       <div class="somediv4">
      <div class="single-row">
         <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="somediv1">
  <div class="single-row">
         <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="single-row">
         <p id="product-name">product name 1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I look for..!

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

1. Your main issue is that `.index()`, with [no arguments](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index), gets the index of the first element in the set you call it on relative to its **siblings**. You want the other form of `index` you had commented-out (`index` [taking an argument](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element)), but you passed in the wrong element. The one you want to pass in can be found via `$(this).closest(".single-parent")`. (Or, as [Sumodh Nair points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52006511/157247), you can use the form [accepting a string](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector).)
2. `id` values **must** be unique on the page. Change those `id="product-name"` to `class="product-name"`. (You might be able to get away with not changing this, but it's still incorrect and needs changing.)

Updated example:

```js
$(document).on('click', ".product-name", function(e) {
  var index = $(".single-row").index($(this).closest(".single-row"));
  alert(index);
})
```

```html
<div class="somediv1">
  <div class="somediv2">
    <div class="somediv3">
      <div class="single-row">
        <p class="product-name">product name 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="somediv1">
  <div class="somediv2">
    <div class="somediv3">
      <div class="somediv4">
        <div class="single-row">
          <p class="product-name">product name 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="somediv1">
  <div class="single-row">
    <p class="product-name">product name 3</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="single-row">
  <p class="product-name">product name 4</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```